# How to add hint in the TextFormField in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, text, dart, hint

I have the below code for the text field using the TextFormField. But I don't see any attribute of function in TextFormField like we used to see in TextField in Android to add a label or hint. How can I add it?

[image]

Answer (score 12):

[image: hinttext vs labelText]

You can use **hintText** and **labelText**.

```
TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'labelText'),
          ),
          TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'hintText'),
          ),
          TextField(
            decoration:
                InputDecoration(hintText: 'both', labelText: 'both'),
          ),
```

[More Information- TextFormField and TextField PlaceHolder](https://androidride.com/textformfield-flutter-placeholder/#hinttext_vs_labeltext)

Answer (score 6):

Hint is not available as its direct available attribute or function but it was under the decorations you can select in the menu you have. Under that you can find label and hint.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            alignLabelWithHint: true,
            labelText: "Your_Hint_and_Label"),
      ),
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

```
decoration: InputDecoration( hintText: "YOUR HINT")
```